# Is chrome incognito mode really incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I opened my chrome browser today incognito mode and went to youtube and opened a video and wasn't logged in but I noticed youtube video suggestions are weirdly similar to what it would suggest when I would login. Is this an issue with my browser settings or incognito mode is just fooling us?

Comment: It just deletes the trail after you close it.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not.

The default incognito page states: "...However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, *or the websites you visit*."

There are a variety of ways you could have been tracked:

- IP Address association
- Being logged into Google via Youtube or the
  Chrome Browser
- Embedded tracking linked to your [localstorage](http://www.pcworld.com/article/205950/ad_network_abuses_html5_privacy_advocates_cry_foul.html)
- Good ol' fashioned malware